# Getting hadoop pipes to work on os x with file access

Tags: c++, macos, hadoop

my apologies if this question is trivial, but I haven't been able to solve it properly despite spending a few hours on google…

I have compiled and installed hadoop 2.5.2 from source on OS X 10.8. I think all went well with this, even though getting the native libraries compiled was a bit of a pain.

To verify my installation, I tried the examples that ship with hadoop like this:

```
$ hadoop jar /Users/per/source/hadoop-2.5.2-src/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.2.jar  pi 2 5
```

which gives me back

```
Job Finished in 1.774 seconds
Estimated value of Pi is 3.60000000000000000000
```

So that seems to indicate that hadoop is at least working, I think.

Since my end goal is to get this working with file I/O from a C++ program using pipes, I also did try the following as an intermediate step:

```
$ hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input
$ hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.2.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

Which also seems to work (as in producing the correct output).

Then, finally, I tried the wordcount.cpp example, and this is not working, although I fail to understand how to fix it. The error message is quite clear.

```
 2015-10-21 13:38:33,539 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: No groups available for user per
 2015-10-21 13:38:33,678 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping: Error getting groups for per: getgrouplist: error looking up group. 5 (Input/output error)
```

So obviously there is something I don't get with the file permissions, but what? My hdfs-site.xml file looks like this, where I have tried to turn off permissions checks altogether.

```
 <configuration>
  <property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
   <name>dfs.web.ugi</name>
    <value>per</value>
  </property>
  <property>
   <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
   </property>
 </configuration>
```

But I am confused since I at least seem to be able to use grep on files in hdfs (per the built-in example above).

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. I am running all of this as myself, so I haven't created a new user for only hadoop, since I am only running it locally on my laptop for now.

Edit: Update with some additional output from my terminal window, according to the discussion below:

```
<snip>
 15/10/21 14:47:41 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
 15/10/21 14:47:41 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
 15/10/21 14:47:41 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
 15/10/21 14:47:41 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local676909674_0001
 java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Application.<init>(Application.java:104)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.PipesMapRunner.run(PipesMapRunner.java:69)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
 <snip>
```

I can add more if that is relevant

Comment: From the error reported it looks like the username "per" which you specify as dfs.web.ugi either does not exist or is not member of groups at all

Comment: Yeah, so how do I fix that :-) ?

Comment: I would try to change this line <value>per</value> setting a real user with some permission instead of "per"

Comment: Ah, thanks, but that is actually the real user, and the only one that exists on my computer.

Comment: Reading better that permission problem seems to be a warning which is not supposed to stop your process, any other error after that?

Comment: Ok, thanks again. This is from the stdout in the terminal window 15/10/21 14:37:18 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local341729831_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)

Comment: Ok, for what it's worth, I could get the whole thing working by trying it with Ubuntu in a virtual machine instead. I need to check whether I did something differently in setting everything up, but now it works. Thanks!